# Сохранение данных Touch ID в ios 8

Tags: ios, swift, touch

Здравствуйте, как использовать Touch ID много информации, а вот как сохранять эти данные я ничего не нашел. Хотел написать небольшую программу, в которой можно было бы регистрироваться и авторизоваться через отпечаток пальцев. Может кто сталкивался с сохранением этих отпечатков, в коком формате это вообще? Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можете сохранить данные в `NSUserDefaults`:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:someObject forKey:"SomeKey"];
```

туда вы можете сохранять только простые объекты - **NSNumber** и **NSString**, а так же **Bool**